# How do I tell slf4j to write log messages from my program to the "Log.txt” file?

Tags: slf4j

```
catch (Exception e) {
    CustomException customExc= new CustomException("Exception wrap", e);
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Class3.class);
    log.error("Error",customExc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SLF4J is just a layer on top of another logging package. All logging calls are passed through to the underlying logging software, which logs the message according to that software's configuration. In other words, SLF4J doesn't write directly to any log files.

You will have to select the "real" logging package that you want to use, and configure it the correct way. The only configuration that you do with SLF4J is to deploy your application with the correct SLF4J jar to make SLF4J use the selected real logging package.

[Here is the SLF4J Manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html). It describes the logging packages that are supported and how everything fits together.

If you're not familiar with the different logging packages, you should focus on Log4J or java.util.logging. Log4J is probably the most popular logging package, while java.util.logging is provided with the JDK.